# Parse xml data which is stored as string

Tags: android, string, xml-parsing

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><loginResponse xmlns="https://comm1.get.com/"><loginResult>true</loginResult><result>success</result></loginResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to parse a string  which has xml data?

i want to get the result success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SOAP response and you might want to try this library: http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/

It claims to be useful for small / limited environments like phones.

If you can use it then there is no need to write another parser in SAX,DOM,Xmlpull etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a very small xml to parse its better to use [dom parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) here.
Also refer [SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)